# Why doesn't fixed width height for image work for higher resolution like 1920X1080 and non-native resolution?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #ffff99;
      /*moe*/
    }
    
    #map_border {
      width: 740px;
      height: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: #000000;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="map_border">

  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I want the black rectangle to be of fixed width and height irrespective of any screen resolution. I have even used auto.

It works for some of the native screen resolutions in my laptop like 1600X900, 1280X720, and 1024X768 but doesn't work for high resolution like 1920X1080 which is also a native resolution and other non-native resolution.

1920X1080 resolution:
[image]

1600X900 resolution:
[image]

As you can see the rectangle should be smaller for high resolution 1920X1080 when compared to one with 1600X900. I made sure the browser is not zoomed. I checked with IE, Firefox, and Chrome. Same thing. I wonder if its the issue with my graphics display.

Comment: For me (Chrome 43, Win 7) your code works exactly like I'd expect.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am working on Windows 8.1 Chrome 44 and it doesn't work for the resolutions i mentioned. But i have access to windows 7  and yes you r right. It works perfectly fine there. Not sure why not on windows 8. Any comments please.

Comment: Ensure that your browser isn't zoomed in by pressing `CTRL+0` on your keyboard. I'm Win 7 and Chrome 44 and it looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I made sure it wasn't zoomed and I even reinstalled chrome but i still don't get it right.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of your issue in Win 8?

Comment: I have added the screenshot and a comment. Please check. Thanks

Comment: Does this still happen when all margins are zero?

Comment: Yeah there are no margins. I don't even have access to another laptop with high screen resolution to check.

Comment: On the 1920 screen, the rectangle is exactly 1.5× the size it has on the other screens, so my guess is that this device has a 1.5dppx ratio.